# Access VBA - how can i convert a value in recordset from text to number?

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have the following code in Access:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdEPH As DAO.QueryDef    
Dim rsEPH As DAO.Recordset  

Set qdEPH = DBEngine(0)(0).QueryDefs("MyQuery")  

qdEPH.Parameters(0) = Text10.Value

Set db = CurrentDb

Set rsEPH = qdEPH.OpenRecordset

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
oSheet.Activate

Dim Count as Long
Count = 1

Do While Not rsEPH.EOF

    oSheet.Range("A" & Count).Value = rsEPH("Value1")
    Count = Count + 1
    rsEPH.MoveNext

Loop
```

A user puts a value in textbox `Text10` on a form and clicks a button to run the code above. It runs the query `MyQuery` and dumps the results into a recordset named `rsEPH`. One of the fields, `Value1`, is stored as a text value in the table being queried. However, it's actually a number. How can I convert `rsEPH("Value1")` to a number (returning Null or something if it fails) and then divide it by 100?

Comment: Try `=CDbl(rsEPH("Value1"))` if you need decimal precision, or `=CLng(rsEPH("Value1"))` if you only need integer?

Comment: With that, I get `Run-time error: 94 - Invalid Use of Null`. One or more of the records may have nothing in `Value1`. Is there a way to handle Null values? In C#, I would do `TryParse` or something like that.

Comment: Looks like Access has a built-in function to convert null values, see @HansUp's answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Nz` to transform Nulls in the text field before you apply the numeric conversion function.  I chose `CDbl` as the conversion function.

```
oSheet.Range("A" & Count).Value = CDbl(Nz(rsEPH("Value1"), "0"))
```

But you mentioned dividing by 100, so maybe you want this ...

```
oSheet.Range("A" & Count).Value = CDbl(Nz(rsEPH("Value1"), "0")) / 100
```

Comment: ah yes .. `Nz` .. I always forget about that! Thanks Hans!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Do While Not rsEPH.EOF

  oSheet.Range("A" & Count).Value = IIf(IsNull(rsEPH("Value1")), 0, CDbl(rsEPH("Value1")))
    Count = Count + 1
    rsEPH.MoveNext

Loop
```